# React navigation 5 alfa cannot navigate between nested child from different parent navigators

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

This is my App navigators file:

```
const SettingStack = createStackNavigator();
const settingStackScreen = () => {
    return (
        <SettingStack.Navigator >
            <SettingStack.Screen name="Setting" component={SettingScreen} />
            <SettingStack.Screen name="Detail" component={DetailScreen} />
        </SettingStack.Navigator>
    );
}

const ElegantStack = createStackNavigator();
const elegantStackScreen = () => {
    return (
        <ElegantStack.Navigator >
            <ElegantStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
            <ElegantStack.Screen name="Todos" component={TodosScreen} />
        </ElegantStack.Navigator>
    );
}

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();
const appNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationNativeContainer >
            <Tab.Navigator >
                <Tab.Screen name="Elegant" component={elegantStackScreen} />
                <Tab.Screen name="Setting" component={settingStackScreen} />
            </Tab.Navigator>
        </NavigationNativeContainer>
    );
}
```

and also this is my HomeScreen file:

```
const home = () => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    return (
        <View style={styles.screen}>
            <Text>Home</Text>

            <Button title="Go Detail" onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('Detail') }} />
            <Button title="Go Todos" onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('Todos') }} />

        </View>
    );
}
```

I want to navigate from home screen to detail screen
but at first, it does not work
after manually going to setting tab
it will work for next tries
Does anyone have any idea about this?

I am using react-navigation5-alfa and react-native 0.61.1

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution just now.

Here is the method that you should follow as mentioned in the docs.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator

In your case this should be,

```
navigation.navigate('Setting', {
  screen: 'Detail',
  params: { key: 'value' },
});
```